# Select values from a table if the table name has timestamp in postgreSQL from R

Tags: r, postgresql, timestamp

I connected from R to the PostgreSQL and i am able to write a table by using timestamp as table name, But i am unable to extract the values.

I used the following code.

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),dbname = 'postgres', 
       host = 'hostname', 
       port = 5432, 
       user = 'username',
       password = 'pwd')
tm<-paste0('job_status_',Sys.time())
dbWriteTable(con,tm,jbs)
dbGetQuery(con,paste0('select * from ',tm))
```

When I ran the `select` command, I got the following syntax error.

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: select * from job_status_2019-03-12 04:33:08
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?!

Answer (score 1):

As your table name contains characters `- :`, it needs to be quoted with `"` to be understood as a table name.

```
dbGetQuery(con,paste0('select * from "',tm, '"'))
```

BTW. It may be a good idea to avoid unusual characters in tables' names and limit yourself to just letters, digits and underscore (`_`). To achieve that you can utilize `gsub()`.

```
tm<-gsub('-|:| ', '_', paste0('job_status_',Sys.time()))
dbWriteTable(con,tm,jbs)
dbGetQuery(con,paste0('select * from ',tm))
```